# Compiling PHP with modified DEBUG_ZEND level

Tags: php, makefile, configure, php-extension, php-internals

I'm debugging a PHP extension and found this while poking through the PHP source code:

```
#if DEBUG_ZEND>=2
    printf("Reducing refcount for %x (%x): %d->%d\n", *zval_ptr, zval_ptr, Z_REFCOUNT_PP(zval_ptr), Z_REFCOUNT_PP(zval_ptr) - 1);
#endif
```

So I want to compile with DEBUG_ZEND set to 2. In `Zend/zend_compile.h`, I saw:

```
#define DEBUG_ZEND 0
```

I edited that value to be 2 instead, and then tried the usual:

```
./configure --enable-debug
make
```

`make` does its thing for awhile, but then I see a bunch of `Reducing refcount for ...` messages and then `make` fails:

```
make: *** [ext/phar/phar.phar] Error 255
```

If I set `DEBUG_ZEND` back to 0, PHP compiles fine. The only reference I could find to `DEBUG_ZEND` was in this bug report:

http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45761

This snippet looked relevant:

> I reconfigured by adding CFLAGS="-DDEBUG_ZEND=2" to the start of the configure command, did a 'make clean', then 'make' ...

So I added `CFLAGS="-DDEBUG_ZEND=2"` right after the shebang in `configure` and was able to compile. However, I ddin't see any extra output about refcounts when running my scripts, so I'm not really convinced it did anything.

What's the proper way of compiling PHP with `DEBUG_ZEND` set to 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the environment variable after the configure script it doesn't affect ./configure. You want to set the variable *for* the configure script.

```
CFLAGS="-DDEBUG_ZEND=2" ./configure --enable-debug
```